# Limit representation of the exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, exponential-function

A well known fact is that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{a}{n}\right)^n=e^a$$

Now I was wondering what if $a$ also depends on $n$? In particular take $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{a+cn}{n}\right)^n$$

is it possible to say that this behaves as $e^{a+cn}$ for large $n$?

With 'behaves' I mean something like: does $$\left(1+\frac{a+cn}{n}\right)^nb^{cn}$$ have the same limit (for $n\to\infty$) as $e^{a}(eb)^{cn}$?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It can easily be shown that this new limit diverges to $\infty$, if that's what you mean to do

Comment: No, I don't want the limit, I mean it's clear that it diverges to $+\infty$. I am interested in the concrete behaviour, but thanks for the comment, I'll clarify the question.

Comment: What you want to evaluate then is
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\left(1 + \frac{a+cn}{n} \right)^n}{e^{a + cn}}
$$

Comment: Yes. So I guess basically my question comes down to whether the limit you posted is $1$ or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(1+\frac{a+cn}{n})^n=(1+c+\frac{a}{n})^n=(1+c)^n(1+\frac{\frac{a}{1+c}}{n})^n\sim(1+c)^ne^\frac{a}{1+c}$ where $\sim$ means that the quotient of two sides tends to 1 as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Now if $c$ is close enough to 0, we have $1+c\approx e^c$, so we can write $(1+\frac{a+cn}{n})^n\approx e^{cn}\cdot e^\frac{a}{1+c}=e^{cn+\frac{a}{1+c}}$. Again, if $c\approx 0$, then $\frac{a}{1+c}\approx a$, so we can say that, in certain informal sense, $(1+\frac{a+cn}{n})^n\approx e^{cn+a}$.

As for existence of the limit, note that $\frac{(1+c)^ne^\frac{a}{1+c}}{e^{cn+a}}\frac{(1+c)^n}{(e^c)^n}\cdot\frac{e^\frac{a}{1+c}}{e^a}=(\frac{1+c}{e^c})^n\cdot e^{\frac{a}{1+c}-a}$. The limit of this expression can only exist and be non-zero if $\frac{1+c}{e^c}=1$, which is possible only for $c=0$. So as long as we have $c\neq 0$ then limit in question does not exist.

Comment: Ok thanks! But I am still a little confused about the formal and informal sense here. So is it not rigorously possibly to deduce that $\left(1+\frac{a+cn}{n}\right)^nb^{cn}$ has the same limit (for $n\to\infty$) as $e^{a}(eb)^{cn}$? And how does it depend on $c$ i.e. what is "close enough" in this context?

Comment: @MichaelPreischl In this context "close enough" is precisely the informal part. What I mean with this is that $\frac{e^c}{1+c}\rightarrow 1$ as $c\rightarrow 0$. As for the former question, we can easily guarantee that both expressions have limit equal to 0, by taking $b$ sufficiently small.

Comment: If you want these two expressions have the same _non-zero_ limit, note that for the latter we need to take $b=1/e$, which doesn't work for the former expression.

Comment: And is it possible to say that "b sufficiently small" means $b<e^{-1}$ or is this again prohibited by the informality?

Comment: @MichaelPreischl I think we need $|b|<e^{-1}$ and $|b|<|1+c|$ for the limits to be 0, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Too bad, that's the kind of statement I was hoping to prove. But thanks anyway you definitely answered my question!